# Permissions not being enforced properly

Tags: php

I am not sure why this is not working but what I am trying to say in the code below is that if the user is not logged in `if ((!isset($username)) && (!isset($userid))){`, then view the form else if they are logged in then display message stating they they must be logged out to view the page.

Problem is though is that even though the user is logged in, it still displays the form and not the message.

Below is the code:

```
        <?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
        session_start();

        include('member.php');

  $user = (isset($_POST['user'])) ? $_POST['user'] : '';
  $email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';

        if ((!isset($username)) && (!isset($userid))){

            echo "<form action='./forgotpass.php' method='post'>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id='errormsg'>$errormsg</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='user' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='email' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='resetbtn' value='Reset Password' /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>";

        }
        else
        {
        echo "Please Logout to view this Page.";    
        }
        ?>
```

In top of the code above I am including the member.php page and I don't know if this makes a big difference but the code for the member.php page is below:

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherforename'])) {

$_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $_SESSION['teacherforename'];

}

if (isset($_SESSION['teachersurname'])) {

$_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $_SESSION['teachersurname'];

}

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherid'])) {

      $userid = $_SESSION['teacherid'];

  }

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherusername'])) {

      $username = $_SESSION['teacherusername'];

  }

        ?>
```

Comment: are you setting `$username` at all?

Comment: do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see what's in there. Most likely you haven't "cleaned up" after a logout, leaving some data in there that you think isn't.

Comment: Why are you not simply checking for the session variables directly and what is the point of the first two `if` statements in `member.php`?

Comment: It is ok, got it working, I had to include a session_start() in the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[check this you tried](http://codepad.org/NSqopNjq)

```
<?php    
$user = (isset($_POST['user'])) ? $_POST['user'] : '';
  $email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';

        if ((!isset($username)) && (!isset($userid))){
       echo 'empty set';
}
```

the above will output the empty set it mean the $user and $email is set

to make it correct also use the `empty()`

correct one

```
$user = (isset($_POST['user'])) ? $_POST['user'] : '';
  $email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';

        if ((!isset($username)) && !empty($username) &&  (!isset($userid) && !empty($email ))){
       echo 'empty set';
}
```

Comment: This could be very helpful as well

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's set AND if it has any value at all.

```
if ( (!isset($username) && empty($username)) && (!isset($userid) && empty($userid)) ){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = (isset($_POST['user'])) ? $_POST['user'] : NULL;
$email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : NULL;
```

I believe setting the variables to '' will return true to `isset()`

[isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)
    `Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.`

Comment: Neither `$user` nor `$email` are part of the `if` statement, so that bug shouldn't be the one causing the undesired behavior.